# Liaison entre un nom et adjectif

Tags: liaisons

Je lisais aujourd'hui un commentaire de livre qui commençait par « Brás Cuba, le "défunt auteur" (et non l'auteur défunt, car il écrit sa biographie après être mort) ... »

Quand communément on prononcerait "défunt auteur" avec la liaison, je me demandais s'il fallait la faire dans ce cas où "défunt" prenait la valeur de nom et "auteur" celle d'adjectif. Mon réflexe serait de ne pas la faire.

Y a-t-il une règle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il me semble que tu as raison : « défunt » semble prendre la valeur d'un nom ici tandis qu' « auteur » fonctionne en tant qu'adjectif pour former un [mot composé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9).

La liaison entre un nom au singulier et un adjectif qui suit est bien interdite selon l'article Wikipédia sur la liaison, en particulier la [liaison interdite](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_interdite).

Sous ce titre est cité un exemple tiré de Roman Jakobson :

> (a) *un savant*‿ *Anglais* (liaison) : un Anglais qui serait savant
>   
> (b) *un savant* X *anglais* (pas de liaision) : un savant qui serait anglais

La liaison sert ici d'élément différenciant : comme la liaison se fait entre un adjectif et un nom, si on l'entendait on aurait entendu (a) ; mais comme la liaison est interdite entre un nom au singulieur et un adjectif, si on ne l'entendait pas on aurait entendu (b).

On dira donc « le défunt auteur » sans liaison s'il s'agit d'un défunt qui est auteur, mais avec liaison s'il s'agit d'un auteur qui est défunt.

Il ne nous choquera en rien d'apprendre qu'il y a plus que le profil phonémique qui détermine la liaison. La phonologie interagit avec la morphologie et la syntaxe (et réciproquement) lorsqu'on cherche à s'avoir quelles sont les unités fonctionnelles et les frontières entre elles.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que les liaisons sont purement une question de phonétique et n’ont pas grand chose à voir avec la classe grammaticale des mots.

De plus je pense qu’il est faux de considérer que l’ordre des mots définit leur classe grammaticale. Sauf erreur "auteur" est toujours un nom. "Défunt" peut être un nom ou un adjectif.

Si le texte que vous aviez lu avait parlé d’un escargot qui fait de la peinture, il aurait pu commencer par

> xxx, "l’escargot peintre"

Escargot et peintre sont tous 2 des noms. Les guillemets sont là pour souligner, comme dans votre exemple d’ailleurs, la relative incongruïté de l’expression. Mais dans votre exemple, on ne peut comprendre qu’après avoir reçu une explication de texte que "défunt" est effectivement utilisé en tant que nom, les guillemets ou l’ordre des mots nous mettant tout au plus sur la piste d’un possible jeu de mot...

Comment: Si, la phonologie interagit souvent avec la morphologie et également quand il s'agit de la liaison. La syntaxe aussi. Il y a certaines frontières que franchit la liaison et d'autres non, les frontières pouvant être phonologiques, morphologiques, ou syntaxiques. Voir [ici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)#Constraints_on_liaison) pour en apprendre davantage. J'en ferai peut-être une autre réponse si je peux.